# Stack multiple libnotify popups

Tags: linux, bash, popup, libnotify

Does anybody know how i can get multiple popups sent via notify-send to appear on screen at once.

With:

```
$ notify-send 'Message One' 'Body One' & notify-send 'Message Two' 'Body Two' & notify-send 'Message Three' 'Body Three'
```

Each one waits for the previous popup in the queue to expire before being shown, i'm trying to get all three to cascade down the screen asap.

Man says:

```
OPTIONS
       -u, --urgency=LEVEL Specifies the urgency level (low, normal, critical).

       -t, --expire-time=TIME
              Specifies the timeout in milliseconds at which to expire the notification.

       -i, --icon=ICON[,ICON...]
              Specifies an icon filename or stock icon to display.

       -c, --category=TYPE[,TYPE...]
              Specifies the notification category.

          Help options:

       -?, --help
              Show this help message

       -h, --hint=TYPE:NAME:VALUE
              Specifies basic extra data to pass. Valid types are int, double, string and byte.
```

Setting the urgency to critical makes no difference.

TIA

Comment: I get all three notifications at the same time.

Comment: Really!? just tried on my ubuntu system and still one after the other.

Comment: Yep, on a Ubuntu 9.04 system.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I know it's an old question, but I ran into it while searching for related stuff in Google, so I will post an answer anyways.

Like tlvince said, it's your notification daemon's fault and you're probably running Canonical's notify-osd. Replace it with Gnome's notification-daemon and you will get the behavior your want.

These pages might help:

http://www.webupd8.org/2011/05/how-to-use-standard-gnome-notification.html

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1663840

Comment: That was exactly it, thanks very much Vitor, they look a bit minty but work much better.

Comment: By the way, if running gnome-shell, it has its own notification panel at the bottom of the screen so I find it useful to disable either notify-osd and gnome's old notification system: http://www.killertechtips.com/2009/04/26/disable-notifications-in-ubuntu-904-jaunty-jackalope/

Answer (score 2):

I believe it's the responsibility of the notification-daemon you are running as to what the behaviour should be. For example, in `xfce4-notifyd`, all three notifications are displayed at once, overlapping each other (since it doesn't support stacking).

Since your running Ubuntu 9.04, your notification-daemon is most likely [notifyOSD](https://launchpad.net/notify-osd). Try taking a look through its documentation.